# PInvoke and POINT

Tags: c#, c++, interop, pinvoke, point

My unmanaged C++ DLL has a function with a POINT out parameter:

```
void GetPosition(int iItemIndex, POINT *pt)
```

I am trying to PInvoke the function in my C# application:

```
[DllImport(@"unmanaged.dll")]
public static extern void GetPosition(int iItemIndex, System.Drawing.Point pt);
```

My question is, should I use System.Drawing.Point as the C# equivalent of POINT? Modifying the unmanaged code is an option. Should I use two `long`s instead?

```
void GetPosition(int iItemIndex, long *x, long *y)
```

Comment: I would recommend a Struct with the same members as POINT

Comment: http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Structures/POINT.html. Sample implementation and a note that your method is ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`POINT` is a C structure, its pinvoke equivalent is a C# struct with two members of type *int*.  System.Drawing.Point already is a perfectly good candidate, no need to write your own.

Beware however that your C# declaration is incorrect.  The C declaration uses a POINT*, a pointer to a POINT structure.  C declarations are often *ambiguous*.  It can mean that the POINT is passed by reference so that the function fills in the members.  Or can mean that the caller is supposed to pass an *array* of POINT structures.  So either of these two C# declarations would be a match:

```
  public static extern void GetPosition(int iItemIndex, out Point pt);
  public static extern void GetPosition(int iItemIndex, Point[] points);
```

The array version is highly unlikely, you'd expect the C programmer to use the plural GetPositions().  And there's a problem in that it won't know how large the array is, C arrays are very primitive and have no baked-in Length property.

So surely the proper declaration is:

```
  [DllImport(@"unmanaged.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
  public static extern void GetPosition(int iItemIndex, out Point pt);
```

Do note that I added the CallingConvention property, it is the default for C code.  Remove it if you know for sure that it uses __stdcall.

Comment: But, if I write my own structure with two members of type int, how would PInvoke know which of the members to assign `POINT.x` and which one to assign `POINT.y`? Do I need to name the members `x` and `y`?

Comment: No, the pinvoke marshaller has no idea what the C names are, all it can see is your declaration.  Structures are copied field by field, the name doesn't matter.  If it is a very simple structure, like this one, then it is *blittable*, a simple memory copy does the job.